# Remove required on input after onchange function

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to make 1 field required if another file with same name index is changed, but if I emptying that field it still requiring value for another field. How to counter this problem?

I'm not comfortable using Javascript and this is my best solution.

```js
function req(id){
var f_id = id;
 document.getElementById(f_id).required = true;
}
```

```html
<form>

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="price[1]" name="price[1]" min=0.00 step=0.01 placeholder="RM" onchange="req('qty[1]')"> 
      
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="qty[1]" name="qty[1]" min=0 placeholder="ekor" onchange="req('price[1]')"> 

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="price[2]" name="price[2]" min=0.00 step=0.01 placeholder="RM" onchange="req('qty[2]')"> 
      
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="qty[2]" name="qty[2]" min=0 placeholder="ekor" onchange="req('price[2]')"> 

<button type=submit>Go</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're best off passing the current field and the one you want to change in to the function, that way you can check the length of the current field, and, if it is empty, remove the requirement from the other one. Something like:

```js
function req(a_id,b_id) {
    a = document.getElementById(a_id)
    b = document.getElementById(b_id)
    if (a.value=="") {
        b.removeAttribute('required');            
    } else {
        b.setAttribute('required','required');
    }
}
```

```html
<form>

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="price[1]" name="price[1]" min=0.00 step=0.01 placeholder="RM" onchange="req('price[1]','qty[1]')"> 
      
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="qty[1]" name="qty[1]" min=0 placeholder="ekor" onchange="req('qty[1]','price[1]')"> 

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="price[2]" name="price[2]" min=0.00 step=0.01 placeholder="RM" onchange="req('price[2]','qty[2]')"> 
      
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="qty[2]" name="qty[2]" min=0 placeholder="ekor" onchange="req('qty[2]','price[2]')"> 

<button type=submit>Go</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use removeAttribute like so:

```
let elmentID = "price[1]";
document.getElementById(elmentID).removeAttribute('required');
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you take over the case in the onchange clears the field.
You could try the following:

```js
function req(element,id){
var f_id = id;
if(element.value == 0){
 document.getElementById(f_id).required = false;
 } else {
 document.getElementById(f_id).required = true;
 }
}
```

```html
  <form>

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="price[1]" name="price[1]" min=0.00 step=0.01 placeholder="RM" onchange="req(this,'qty[1]')"> 
      
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="qty[1]" name="qty[1]" min=0 placeholder="ekor" onchange="req(this,'price[1]')"> 

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="price[2]" name="price[2]" min=0.00 step=0.01 placeholder="RM" onchange="req(this,'qty[2]')"> 
      
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="qty[2]" name="qty[2]" min=0 placeholder="ekor" onchange="req(this,'price[2]')"> 

<button type=submit>Go</button>
</form>
```

I have added the element that is modified to the red function and do a check on its value.